# i am only getting the output right if i say i is int specially in for loop

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
                    // finding the required sum of subarray
int main()
{
    
int n,s;
int i=0,j=0,st=-1,en=-1,sum=0;
cin>>s;                            //input required sum
cin>>n;
int a[n];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){     // here if i only mention int again i //am getting the output or else the values of st and en are printing //out the same as i initialize
    cin>>a[i];
}
while (j<n){
    sum+=a[j];
    while(sum>s){
        sum-=a[i];
        i++;
    }
    if(sum==s){
        st=i+1;
        en=j+1;
        break;
    }
    j++;
}
cout<<st<<" "<<en<<" ";

return 0;
```

the output is -1 -1
and if i mention "int i" again in for loop of inputing array i a getting  the answer.
i want to know the reason i already intialize i before why do i need to do it again

Comment: You need a different counter for `b`.  What happens when some pass looking for some `a[i]` is nowhere else in the array ? That `b[i]` slot is skipped, leaving whatever undefined garbage was there before, later to be regurgitated by your final output loop. Use a different run-up counter that is only bumped when you store a new value in `b`, and use *that* as the top-end of your final output loop.

Comment: Also instanciation without initialization is bad. int b[n] will create the array, but will not assign any values. int b[n] = {0} will initalize it properly.

Comment: If you have some working code you would like feedback on, see codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: The problem to solve is unclear. You could detail what is the expected output, with a few examples. Besides, your method seems inefficient O(n^2), maybe not a concern.

Comment: This code should actually not compile, because for `int a[n]` to be valid, `n` must be a compile time constant.

Comment: @wohlstad `This code should actually not compile` VLA are not part of the c++ standard, but many compilers support it. So it should not be used even though it compiles.

Answer (score 1):

The problem statement is unclear, I'm assuming you simply want the indexes of the repeating numbers in array `a`. You are correct for the most part, using `b[i] = i` is the problem. If you understand what a vector is, then simply create a vector like this and push the indexes in the vector. For example,

```
vector<int> b;
```

and inside the `a[i] == a[j]` condition,

```
b.push_back(i);
```

then finally print out result like,

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < b.size() , i++)
    cout << b[i] << " ";
```

If you're unfamiliar with vectors, simply use another variable `cnt` to update index of array `b`

```
int a[n], i, b[n], j, cnt = 0;
```

and inside the `a[i] == a[j]` condition,

```
b[cnt] = i;
cnt++;
```

and finally

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < cnt ; i++)
    cout << b[i] << ' ';
```

Comment: `using b[i] = i is the problem` you should explain why this is a problem.

Comment: `b.push(i);`: an `std::vector` has no member function `push`, it has `push_back`.

Comment: @t.niese fixed it. A proper explanation is already provided in the comments. Still explaining just in case. `b[i] = i` skips over some indexes in `b` array. `cnt` was used to use every index in the array, whenever add new element is being added, it's being added serially. Poster didn't ask for any explanation, he only asked to suggest any changes to the code. Check @WhozCraig 's comment above for better explanation.

Comment: `Poster didn't ask for any explanation` both question and answers should not only help the one asking the question but any future reader. `A proper explanation is already provided in the comments.` a good answer would be self-contained, a comment could be deleted for some reason, so you should not rely on it to exist. (Instead of explaining it in the comments you should add that information to the answer).